# disconnecting a manifold stream without closing other streams

Tags: clojure

If I create two streams and connect the two:

```
(def a (stream/stream))
(def b (stream/stream))
(stream/connect a b)
```

When 'a' is closed 'b' closes

```
(stream/closed? b) => false
(stream/close! a)
(stream/closed? b) => true
```

Is there a way to disconnect 'a' from 'b' without closing 'b'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. According to the doc of `stream/connect`:

> Optionally takes a map of parameters:
>
> ...
>
> - downstream? - if closing the source will close the sink.  Defaults to true.
>
> ...

So, you need to connect your streams as follows:

```
(stream/connect a b {:downstream? false})
```